Firebase putFile() method confusion, how this method works
Recently i have met a lot of questions about a problem with uploading say 'image to firebase'.
This can be done by putFile() method.
according to asynchronous programming concept if the async method returns a value, that value must be in the future.
this putFile() method is returning an UploadTask object to give you a control on the upload process.
How it returns just UploadTask rather than Future<UploadTask> if it's necessary to await for it when uploading the file.
Example to get the view:
// i don't need any control on the upload process, just upload the image

await putFile(file); // works

Note: Removing await will not upload the image.
While:
// i need to control the upload process

UploadTask ut = putFile(file); // works

Got it, how it can return a value not in the future, while just uploading a file requires await.
I read a bit, the problem not revolving around when or whether the upload task begins or not
Questions that represents that problem: 1 , 2
